# Is there a way to change other fields of a column when a field is updated?

Tags: sql-server

```
id status
-------------
1   no
2   yes
3   no
4   yes
5   --
```

when I update the status column to 'yes' of id 5,

I want results like this

```
id    status
-------------
1      no
2      no
3      no
4      no
5      Yes
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by `CASE` statement or `IIF` function.

The query will be:

```
UPDATE SampleTable SET [Status] = CASE WHEN Id = @InputValue THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END;
```

or

```
UPDATE SampleTable SET [Status] = IIF(Id = @InputValue , 'yes', 'no');
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd688548879133a1610451e591152ede)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to have multiple update statements in a transaction depending of your needs, for the above sample you will have :

```
update tableName set status = 'Yes' where id = 5;

update tableName set status = 'no' where id <> 5;
```

Is a good option to have both update queries in a transaction for completing both (either success, or failure)